# Setting up taxonomy field with Pnp PowerShell in SharePoint Online and Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, taxonomy, provisioning, pnp-provision

I am using PnP to set up a number of site collections with the same set of site columns and content types. Initially I created an XML provisioning file from a site I set up, but when I applied it to another site there were issues adding the content types and creating some site columns that were using the term store to lookup values.
So now I am trying to set up the site columns and content types using Pnp PowerShell instead.

I could use some help translating some of the fields in the provisioning xml file to a PnP PowerShell command.

I wonder how to specify the `-ID`, should I use curly brackets or not? And how should I specify the `-TermSetPath`?
In the term store, I have a node XXX, where I have the term set Classification accessible for all sites in my hub. But since this is not open for everyone to add terms, I am planning on finding some PnP command to move those locally for each site.
So I will store "Classification" under the "Site Collection - xx.xxx.com-sites-thisSite" node. In the provisioning xml this is specified as `{termsetid:{sitecollectiontermgroupname}:Classification}`. How do I specify that to the Pnp command?

This is what I got:

The PnP PowerShell command:
 `Add-PnPTaxonomyField -DisplayName "Classification" -InternalName "Classification" -Group "XXX" -ID "cd165a06-9295-438b-90ef-20786be3a1fc" -TermSetPath "TestTermGroup|TestTermSet"`

From the provisioning XML file:

```
<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="Classification" List="{{listid:TaxonomyHiddenList}}" WebId="{siteid}" ShowField="Term1033" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Group="XXX" ID="{cd165a06-9295-438b-90ef-20786be3a1fc}" SourceID="{{siteid}}" StaticName="Classification" Name="Classification" Description="'Classification' is used to specify ...">
          <Default>
          </Default>
          <Customization>
            <ArrayOfProperty>
              <Property>
                <Name>SspId</Name>
                <Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{sitecollectiontermstoreid}</Value>
              </Property>
              <Property>
                <Name>TermSetId</Name>
                <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{termsetid:{sitecollectiontermgroupname}:Classification}</Value>
              </Property>
          </Customization>
        </Field>
```

And there is also another field generated in the provisioning xml, that seems coupled with the field I am trying to add. Do I need to add this field as well?
`<Field Type="Note" DisplayName="Classification_0" StaticName="cd165a069295438b90ef20786be3a1fc" Name="cd165a069295438b90ef20786be3a1fc" ID="{72bd59fd-153c-4ab6-b49b-c40cd77853c8}" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" Required="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" SourceID="{{siteid}}" />`

And (a bonus question) the `List="{{listid:TaxonomyHiddenList}}"` from the provisioning xml file, how is that translated to the PnP command? Do I need to resolve `listid` to something?

Answer (score 0):

You donot have to specify the `-ID` parameter for PnP PowerShell command :`Add-PnPTaxonomyField`. ID will be generated automatically when you create the column.

For `-TermSetPath` parameter, it should be like this `"<Group Name>|<Term Set name>"`. If  you store "Classification" under the "Site Collection - xx.xxx.com-sites-thisSite" node. The TermSetPath shoule be `"Site Collection - xx.xxx.com-sites-thisSite|Classification"`.

Reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-termset-and-taxonomy-field-using-pnp-powershell/

Comment: I thought I needed to add ID to get the same ID for this site column on all my site collections?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$DisplayName = "Departments"
Add-PnPTaxonomyField -List $List -DisplayName $DisplayName -InternalName $DisplayName -TaxonomyItemId f076462d-bde7-4fa4-aa7b-4409a769fcd1
```

Source: https://sposcripts.com/add-sharepoint-columns-with-powershell/#Add_Managed_Metadata_Column